# How to validate .NET dialog items when using automatic DialogResult?

Tags: .net, dialog

At the moment I have setup a custom ok cancel dialog with a drop down in c#. The ok and cancel buttons use the DialogResult property so no code behind it. What I now need to do is validate the drop down to check it isn't left empty before posting back a dialogresult.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [here](http://www.functionx.com/vcsharp2003/Lesson06.htm)

Double-click the  Closing field, and implement it as follows:

```
private void Second_Closing(object sender, 
        System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    // When the user attempts to close the form, don't close it...
    e.Cancel = (dropdown.selecteditemindex >= 0);
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this prevent the user from closing the dialog by using the cancel button or close button?

Answer (score 1):

What I have done for this is to not set the DialogResult on the OK button, but put some code behind the button.

```
private void OkButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.DialogResult = ValueComboBox.SelectedIndex >= 0
        ? DialogResult.Ok
        : DialogResult.None;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Disable your OK button until the combobox is changed to a valid value.

Answer (score 1):

You can keep using the OK and Cancel button functionality of dialogs, and then put this code in the Clicked handler for the OK button:

```
private void OkButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsValid()) {
        this.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.None;
    }
}
```

In the code above, `IsValid()` is a method you have to implement, that validates the input fields on the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

If you want check for something, you allways need some code behind the designer.
For your case, you can use a "Closing" event in the form, check what you need and if you want, set "e.Cancel = true;" - then form will not be closed.